# Unable to install Angular CLI without admin rights and using proxy

Tags: angular-cli

I am trying to install Angular CLI, but because I am not an admin and the company uses some proxy. I get an error

```
 C:\apps\Angular\Learning\HelloWorldAngular> npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reasonnpm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. 
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

This is my company laptop and I do not have admin rights, Is there any way that I could use just the zip version of angular CLI without making any installations.

```
>netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your proxy before using npm. You need to edit file under `Users/YourUser/.npmrc`

Comment: how do I know whats my proxy, because it says null in the file .npmrc

Comment: You should know, what is your proxy... if you dont, check your windows settings

Comment: I have added what I got in the netsh command pllease check. Looks like I dont have proxy

Comment: try to access proxy settings through windows settings - By the error message, it seems like you are behind a proxy

Comment: I cannot see any proxy settings in windows. It seems to be locked by admin